# Lambda@edge access request headers in viewer response function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I've setup a viewer response lambda function that sets a cookie.

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const locale = 'en-gb';
  const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;
  response.headers['set-cookie'] = [{ value: `locale=${locale.toLowerCase()};` }];
  return response;
};
```

This works as expected, but what I'd like to do is parse the request headers for the `cloudfront-viewer-country`. Something like:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
  const countryCodeHeader = request.headers['cloudfront-viewer-country'];
  const locale = countryCodeHeader[0].value; 
  const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;
  response.headers['set-cookie'] = [{ value: `locale=${locale.toLowerCase()};` }];
  return response;
};
```

However this does not work because the request is undefined. Is there a way to access the request inside the viewer response function?

I've read that it's possible to setup an origin request policy to include country and language headers, but how can I make these available in my viewer response function?